# Adding two lists and making the third one - compiles and doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have to make a function, precisely the `+ operator` overloading, where I have two lists, merge them and make a third list, which has elements of that both lists. The elements don't have to be sorted, because it's a template list, where the elements can be matrices or ints, or anything else.

I have a code, which compiles and while it comes to the last line `std::cout << l3;` it prints the random number all the time, I have to shutdown the command window. When I change it to `std::cout << l1;` everything works. So the problem is with the `+ operator` but I have no idea where it might be. Thanks for help.

Here's some code:

```
List() {
    sizeList = 0;
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}

 void add(const T& element) {
    if(head){
        Node *n = new Node(element);
        tail->next = n;
        n->next = 0;
        tail = n;
        sizeList++;
    } else{
        Node *n = new Node(element);
        head = n;
        tail = n;
        head->next = 0;
        tail->next = 0;
        sizeList++;
    }
}

List<T> operator + (List<T> secList){      
    List finList;
    finList.head = 0;
    finList.tail = 0;
    finList.sizeList = 0;
    Node *n = this->head;
    while(n){
        finList.add(n->value);
        n = n->next;
    }
    Node *p = secList.head;
    while(p){
        finList.add(p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }

    return finList;
}
```

and the main:

```
int main(){

    List<int> l1;
    List<int> l2;
    List<int> l3;

    std::cin >> l1;
    std::cin >> l1;
    std::cin >> l1;
    std::cin >> l2; 
    std::cin >> l2;  
    std::cout << std::endl;

    l3 = l1 + l2;

    std::cout << l3;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I have made an assignment operator, which looks like this:

```
List<T> operator = (List<T> secList){
    List assignList;
    Node *n = this->head;
    while(n){
        assignList.add(n->value);
        n = n->value;
    }
    return assignList;
}
```

How should the copy constructor look like? Should it be similar to the `= operator` ?

Comment: I assume you follow [the rules of three or five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five)? It's a little hard to know without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't forget the copy-assignment operator either.

Comment: Do you need to copy the list for + operator? Passing by reference could solve the problem (well, hide the problem for now).

Comment: I've edited the post and have another question up

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0):

The `operator +` is not that bad, even if you copy objects when you could use a const reference:

```
List<T> operator + (const List<T>& secList){ 
    ...
```

But the assignment operator just does not work: it never changes the current instance. As a quick fix, you could do:

```
List<T>& operator = (const List<T>& secList){
    using std::swap;
    List assignList;
    Node *n = this->head;
    while(n){
        assignList.add(n->value);
        n = n->value;
    }
    swap(head, assignList.head);
    swap(tail, assignList.tail);
    swap(listSize, assignList.listSize);

    return *this;
}
```

As this swaps the current instance content with the automatic `assignList`, previous nodes belonging the previous list of `this` will be destroyed by the destructor of `assignList`.

Anyway to most common way is the copy and swap pattern as you need a copy operator:

```
List(const List<T>& other) {
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
    sizeList = 0;
    for (const Node<T> *n=other.head; n!=nullptr; n = n->next) {
        add(n->value);
    }
}
List<T>& operator = (const List<T>& secList){
    using std::swap;
    List assignList = secList;
    swap(head, assignList.head);
    swap(tail, assignList.tail);
    swap(listSize, assignList.listSize);
    return *this;
}
```

And do not forget to implement or declare deleted the move constructor and the move assignment operator...